# Disable auto-saving in UIManagedDocument

Tags: ios, core-data, uimanageddocument

Is there any way to disable auto-save for `UIManagedDocument` ?

I present `NSManagedObjects` in a controller where the user can add and delete them. But I just want to save those changes when the user explicitly fires a save action. Otherwise I want to discard  the changes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what happen if your app crashed/get killed and user have no change to press save button?

Comment: That is a good point. For my situation though it is good to revert to the previous state. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you override the method below in the `UIManagedDocument` subclass

```
- (void)autosaveWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler
```

EDIT: Here are some additional methods you might want to include.  I use the first one to confirm if and when auto-saves were happening and the second to debug certain errors, the details of which can't be obtained any other way.  That's all thats in my subclass so its pretty trivial to add this.

```
@implementation YourManagedDocument


- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError
{
    NSLog(@"Auto-Saving Document");
    return [super contentsForType:typeName error:outError];
}

- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error userInteractionPermitted:(BOOL)userInteractionPermitted
{
    NSLog(@" error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    NSArray* errors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(errors != nil && errors.count > 0) {
        for (NSError *error in errors) {
            NSLog(@" Error: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@" error.userInfo = %@", error.userInfo);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to me this is what I will end up doing and passing a flag in the controller I want to disable auto-save. I was hoping though to find some solution that avoided subclassing. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425546/953105) for the details, but unless you explicitly save your `NSManagedObjectContext`, you can call `[managedObjectContext rollback]` to undo any changes the user made.

Comment: That seems the correct approach. However, how does it know until which point to discard changes? The auto-saving happens on an unpredictable way. Thanks for your reply!